# How to nicely call property with side effects?

Tags: c#

This is purely a language matter, **because I know, that this may (and possibly even should) be solved in a different way**.

We have a property `Prop`, which in its getter has some side effects. How to "call" this property in a "nice" way to trigger these side effects?

One way:

```
object dummy = this.Prop;
```

But this doesn't seem to be a nice solution, because it involves creating unnecessary variable. I tried with:

```
(() => this.Prop)();
```

But it doesn't compile. Is there short and clean way to do it?

Comment: Can you change the class containing this property? if so, would be useful to see how the property has been coded

Comment: Move the side effects in getter to separate method ? Also why you have sideeffects in getter ?

Comment: Unless the side effect is related to getting (and wanting to get) the value of `Prop`, it does not make any sense to trigger the side effect this way. As you've seen, you get ugly looking code to trigger the side effect without wanting the value of `Prop`.

Comment: When you you find yourself wanting the side-effect without any use for the property, then it is in the wrong place. Solve the real problem.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar "This is purely a language matter, **because I know, that this may be solved in a different way.**". Let's call it curiosity, if there is a simple and elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create a variable, you'll then get code complaining that it's unused, which can be annoying.

For benchmarking cases, I've sometimes added a generic `Consume()` extension method, which just does nothing:

```
public static void Consume<T>(this T ignored)
{
}
```

You can then write:

```
this.Prop.Consume();
```

and the compiler will be happy. Another alternative would be to put have a method which accepted a `Func<T>`:

```
public static void Consume<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    function();
}
```

Then call it as:

```
Consume(() => this.Prop);
```

I *rarely* face this situation outside tests (both benchmarks, and "I should be able to call the property without an exception being thrown" test) but every so often it *can* be useful, e.g. to force a class to be initialized. Any time you find yourself wanting this, it's worth *considering* whether this would be more appropriate as a method.

Comment: Why not just disable warnings for the line? Using getters for side effects is already not a very pretty thing, a few pragmas won't make it worse.

Comment: @golergka: It depends on the scenario. I would rather make my code express what I'm trying to do, which is *not* to have a variable, but just consume the value. You could think of a clearer name, of course - but fundamentally I don't think there's much of an issue in consuming it like this.

Answer (score 1):

C# 7.0 solved this problem, now you can use [a discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards#a-standalone-discard):

```cs
_ = this.Prop;
```